# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, bool>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a ToDo-App with Flutter to learn Flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ToDo(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class ToDo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const ToDo({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToDoState createState() => _ToDoState();
}

class _ToDoState extends State<ToDo> {
  final Map<String, bool> products = {
    'Tomatoes': false,
    'Cheese': false,
    'Salade': false,
    'Paprika': false,
    'Water': false
  };

  void onSubmit(String title) {
    setState(() {
      products[title] = false;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void newEntry() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: UserInput(
              onSubmit: onSubmit,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  void deleteItem(String key) {
    setState(() {
      products.remove(key);
    });
  }

  void onChanged(String key) {
    setState(() {
      products.update(key, (value) => !value);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("TODO App"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          String key = products.keys.elementAt(i);
          return TodoItem(
            title: key,
            done: products[key]!,
            onDelete: () => deleteItem(key),
            onChanged: () => onChanged(key),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: newEntry,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TodoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final void Function() onChanged;
  final void Function() onDelete;
  final bool done;

  const TodoItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title,
      required this.onDelete,
      required this.done,
      required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          leading: Checkbox(
            value: done,
            onChanged: (value) => onChanged,
          ),
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.black54),
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
            onPressed: onDelete,
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class UserInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(String) onSubmit;

  const UserInput({Key? key, required this.onSubmit(String title)})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserInputState createState() => _UserInputState();
}

class _UserInputState extends State<UserInput> {
  String input = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: "ToDo"),
            onSubmitted: widget.onSubmit,
            onChanged: (value) => input = value,
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => widget.onSubmit(input),
            child: const Text("Save"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ToDo class has a Map<String, bool> containing the ToDos and store whether they are done or not. The class then should show this data in a ListView (with ListView.builder) every single ToDo is being shown through a custom TodoItem Widget.

VSC doesn't show any compilation errors but when I try to run the code with flutter run I get this error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building ToDo(dirty, dependencies:
[_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#93b03]], state: _ToDoState#a990a):
type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, bool>' of 'function result'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  ToDo
  ToDo:file:///C:/<path>/tutorial_project_1/lib/main.dart:17:19

#1      _ToDoState.build (package:tutorial_project_1/main.dart:77:20)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4716:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4774:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2589:33)
#7      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#8      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#9      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)    :5)
#10     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#11     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)                                                                                         g.dart:863:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════  
Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 1 of 582 libraries in 285ms.
```

I used a list instead of a map before, but then I wanted to add the 'checking a task'-feature and the error started to occur.

I hope you can help me figure out and fix the problem.

**EDIT**

So I restarted the emulator and figured that the issue was with exceeding the 64k limit set on android and not enabling multidex and had nothing to do with the app...

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I don't get any errors...
What I did notice was that your checkbox onchanged() didn't worked, so I fixed it by changing this in the TodoItem class:

```
leading: Checkbox(
            value: done,
            onChanged: (value) => onChanged(), // added () after onChanged
          ),
```

And then everything worked just fine.